# Simple "set field =" workflow failing?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, error, path

Multiple users are moving files into my library, and no one cares about the actual document file name, but SharePoint does. So to prevent overwriting "duplicates", I'm using a workflow which appends "Random Text" to whatever the SharePoint ID is. This works half the time. 
I tried it with an "Update Item" action on Path and Name and a "Set Field = " action on Name, but the same inconsistency occurs.

To remedy this, I tried the "delay for __ seconds" trick by calculating 1/60 (1 second) as my delay variable and setting the pause for "delay" minutes. This makes the workflow run without errors 100% of the time, but the process is taking 2-3mins (maybe longer) to complete than it did before I added a pause.

Is there a more efficient way to pause the workflow? Is this just an altogether poor solution?

Comment: I would use an Event Receiver to handle that quick appending of random text to a field. 
Implement the ItemAdding or ItemAdded events and do the update. Can you deploy an event receiver where your solution is hosted?

Comment: Yes I can do sandboxed solutions. Thank you for this suggestion. I will most likely go with something like this.

Answer (score 2):

If you pause the workflow, it gets picked up again the next time the workflow timer job runs. So even if you set it for a fraction of a second, it is effectively paused until the next time the timer job is set to run. The default configuration is 5 minutes I believe and it can be altered via powershell to reduce the time to a minute.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. This is very helpful. We have a separate architect team that would have to approve that request, so I'm not sure I can change that.